# Multiple file upload not processing in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

I am writing an API using Laravel 6 and am having some issues with uploading files, in fact, uploading any files at all.

I'm using Postman to test the API. In the params section, i put in a name, and then over in the body (form-data) section, I enter the key `filename` and then attach a file.

When i send the request, it comes back with the `all good` status, but it doesn't upload the file, or save the details to the database.

Also, if i dont attach a image file, the validator comes back with the required status, but if i change that to a txt file, it doesn't say anything and comes back with the `all good` status, so it seems to be missing the `filename.*` part and only running the first `filename` validation.

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\ImageUpload;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class ImageUploadController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'filename' => 'required',
            'filename.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error validation failed'], 400);
        }

        if ($request->hasFile('filename')) {
            foreach ($request->file('filename') as $image) {
                $fileName = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $image->move(public_path() . '/uploads', $fileName);

                $imageUpload = new ImageUpload();
                $imageUpload->name = $request->name;
                $imageUpload->filename = $fileName
                $imageUpload->save();
            }
        }

        return response()->json(['All good'], 200);
    }
}
```

if i `dd($resposne)` at the very top, the file im trying to upload is there, see below;

```
+files: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag {#59
#parameters: array:1 [
  "filename" => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile {#44
    -test: false
    -originalName: "23367298-7883819-image-m-101_1578974555854.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -error: 0
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpAJtgNw"
    basename: "phpAJtgNw"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpAJtgNw"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpAJtgNw"
    aTime: 2020-01-27 08:59:12
    mTime: 2020-01-27 08:59:12
    cTime: 2020-01-27 08:59:12
    inode: 266560
    size: 96981
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
]
}
```

Comment: check if your `$request` has multiple files and in HTML form `filename[]` as array.

Comment: @Webinion .. Its there ... I have updated my question with the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'filename.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ]);
```

and your postman request put like

```
filename[]  (format type = file) = image1.jpg
filename[]  (format type = file) = image2.jpg
filename[]  (format type = file) = image3.jpg
```